# Why is my instance variable being overwritten inside my Rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I have two variables in my index action in my post controller. However I am using the kaminari gem and it requires that the variable for how many post per pages go in the index action.

However, I have another variable for my search. I don't want to over ride so what is a work around?

```
def index
  @posts = Post.where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
  @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

Comment: Why not just use a different name for either of those variables?

Comment: @Pavan I don't think that was what the OP was trying to do. Kaminari methods needs to be chained after the scoped query to handle the pagination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried

```
@posts = Post.where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

or this

```
@posts = Post.where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
@posts = @posts.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

The way you have it set now the second `@posts` variable will override the first `@posts` variable every time 100% because you are just simply reassigning it.

Comment: you don't need to reassign the instance variable. `@posts = @posts.page...` Instead you can chain method on the next line with `.page(...` and indent to indicate method chaining. see [rubocop style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#consistent-multi-line-chains)

Comment: You mean like the first example?